# Installing R 'greenbrown' package on Mac in R 4.1.2

Tags: macos, installation, packages, r

I recently switched to Mac from Windows and I need to use the 'greenbrown' package to run some code. However, when I try to install as per the online instructions, I get errors that I think are related to gfortran?? I've tried installing 'strucchange' from tar.gz but that didn't help.
Command:

```
install.packages("greenbrown", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Error messages:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0' 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib' 
ld: library not found for -lgfortran clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 
make: *** [strucchange.so] Error 1 
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘strucchange’ removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/strucchange’ 
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘strucchange’ had non-zero exit status 
ERROR: dependencies ‘strucchange’, ‘forecast’ are not available for package ‘bfast’ removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/bfast’ 
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘bfast’ had non-zero exit status 
ERROR: dependencies ‘SDMTools’, ‘jpeg’, ‘bcp’, ‘strucchange’ are not available for package ‘phenopix’ removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/phenopix’ Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘phenopix’ had non-zero exit status 
ERROR: dependencies ‘strucchange’, ‘Kendall’, ‘bfast’, ‘phenopix’, ‘quantreg’ are not available for package ‘greenbrown’ removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/greenbrown’ 
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘greenbrown’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Step1 reinstall

```
brew reinstall gcc
```

Step2 check the directories mentioned in the warning message. If not exist, create them. copy gfortran libraries .../lib/gcc/x/*.* to the directories.

Step3 retry installation of package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).